# Batch update of multiple tables in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, normalization, multiple-tables

I need some help in thinking through the process to do batch update on multiple tables for RoR application. Following are my models,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :addresses  
    has_many :phones  
end  


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :user  
    has_one    :addresstype      
end  


class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :user  
    has_one    :phonetype  
end  


class PhoneType < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :phone  
end  


class AddressType < ActiveRecord::Base      
    belongs_to :address    
end
```

You can imagine "Address" table has user_id, PhoneType has phone_id, and AddressType has address_id keys to maintain associations.

So, I want to process some files with user records to insert into appropriate tables. For e.g.

```
...  
    usr1@foo.com,1234 sw main st. ca 19820,offce,425-378-1188,mobile  
    usr1@foo.com,7869 sw fool st. ca 19820,residential,425-898-2345,landline  
    usr2@foo.com,4321 sw oak st. ca 19822,offce,435-378-1298,mobile  
    usr3@foo.com,8789 sw adler st. ca 19822,residential,436-898-6234,landline  
...
```

millions of them either all in one file or one record per file transfered from remote server.

OR, is there any other way to process these remote requests on demand basis? For e.g. remote  servers send a record to my RoR application and it gets processed thru RoR app.
In both cases I want to make sure data to be inserted passes all validation rules. Like email format is valid, or address can not be empty.

These records could be in json format to save on size of data to be transfered in a file.

While processing user (usr1@foo.com) may or may no exists.

Thanks and I really appreciate any help.

Atarang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both. If you have one file you can simply create a ruby script and include `config/environment.rb` to load the environment of the rails application in your ruby script. Then you can load the file and deal with each line like this:

```
include 'config/environment.rb'
File.open("/folder/folder/file_to_parse", "r").each_line do |line| 
     .....
     # interpret line here
     ....
end
```

If its in CSV format you can also use rubys CSV Librarie (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

On the other hand you could also create an interface that parses the data in JSON. You could use the JSON implementation for ruby (which is documentated here: http://flori.github.com/json/) to create an action that parses a single object thats transfered in JSON.

//About the validations:

Write validations in the Models! Then you check all the Models that `belongs_to` sth. because you may already have the `PhoneType` thats used in the actual record. So care about not getting duplicaties when you dont need them.

After that you use the `new` method to create new objects (not `create` because create writes to the database). Then you parse the line and when the line is parsed you can check all your objects using the `valid?` method which checks if the object passes all the validations defined in the model.

And only if all your objects pass the validation you safe them to the database. Otherway you simply dont execute the `save` method so datasets which dont pass the vaidations arent stored in the databse.

//About th eperformende

If you just have to perform the import once its not that big problem if the script isnt that perfect. What you should do when there are many entries in the table (100 arent many, 100000 are,..) you should add indexes to all the foreign key columns. You can create a migration `addIndexesToForeignKeys` and add indexes with the `add_index` method like this:

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name
```

This will speed up select queries and slow down insert queries a bit but I think show actions will be called more often then create actions ;)

Comment: Davidb,  Thanks for your reply. I'll read more on json. But how about actual inserts. Do I need to  do following (in sequence)? First check for user and insert a new user if not found, next get user_id, get phone_id for phonetype string and address_id for addresstype string. Next insert address record with user_id, addresstype_id, and phone record with user_id, phonetype_id. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, you are right, validations are in the models. And .valid? method could be use for validations. Just to see I understood correctly, so assuming phone and address types are there, in a typical case there will be 3 "SELECTS or call to .find() method" first for user_id (using email address string), then addresstype_id (using address type string), and phonetype_id (using phone type string), And there will be at least 2 new objects, Address and Phone to be validated and saved. Flow sounds ok to me. Right? It raises the question of efficiency or performance of dbserver serving all those queries.

Comment: Davidb, I'll try your suggestions and update this thrread. I really appreciate your time. Thanks.